# How to truncate any table using its synonym in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, truncate, synonym

How to truncate any table using its synonym in oracle?

```
-- in Server_A
Create Table table_a ( col int);

-- in server_B
CREATE SYNONYM syn_table_a FOR table_a@dblink_server_a;

--insert into
INSERT INTO syn_table_a values (1);

--Truncate
How to truncate table using synonym only?.
```

Comment: You can't. See my answer.

Comment: Yes I already found that truncate is not possible. I am using delete operation to empty table. Is there any alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**A truncate statement cannot be used on a synonym.**

> Synonyms cannot be used in a drop table, drop view or truncate
>   table/cluster statements. If this is tried, it results in a ORA-00942:
>   table or view does not exist

For example,

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t(col NUMBER);

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> CREATE SYNONYM t_syn FOR t;

Synonym created.

SQL>
SQL> TRUNCATE TABLE t_syn;
TRUNCATE TABLE t_syn
               *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


SQL>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use dynamic SQL to do it, e.g.:

```
declare
  d varchar2(1000);
begin
  select 'TRUNCATE TABLE "' || table_owner || '"."' || table_name || '"'
  into d
  from all_synonyms
  where synonym_name = 'MYSYNONYM';
  execute immediate d;
end;
```

If the table is accessed via a database link, this will not work. In that case, you could create a procedure on the remote instance that does the truncate, then call that procedure across the database link, e.g.

```
begin
  truncate_my_table@dblinkname;
end;
```

Comment: Table is actually in another server and synonym is using dblink.  Currently I m using delete operation to empty table. Is that a risk.

Comment: Updated answer. You can call a procedure across a database link which could do the truncate.

Comment: I'm not sure what risk you're referring to. Risk of unauthorised use? Risk of errors? Risk of performance issues?

Comment: I am referring to any possible risk using delete instead of truncate other than performance issue.

Comment: There's no risk unless you don't understand the fundamental difference between a delete and a truncate.

Answer (score -1):

In Oracle, you can also get ORA-14410 while trying to drop/truncate a table using synonym.

The alert log:

ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-14410: RPI LOCK TABLE issued to table referenced through synonym

Follow the above dynamic SQl to drop/truncate it.

Comment: Please check this[URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be handy to lift your content quality up